# "Non-categorical" examples of $(\infty, \infty)$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, big-list, examples

This title probably seems strange, so let me explain.

Out of the several different ways of modeling $(\infty, n)$-categories, [complicial
sets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.06801) and [comical sets](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.07603) allow $n = \infty$,
providing mathematical definitions of $(\infty, \infty)$-categories. I've asked people a few times for interesting
examples of $(\infty, \infty)$-categories that could fit into these definitions, and I've always gotten the answer:
the $(\infty, \infty)$-category of (small) $(\infty, \infty)$-categories.

This is not a bad example, and I think it's cool, but I would like to know what kinds of examples are out there
other than just categories of categories. For example, for $(\infty, n)$-categories with $n$ finite,
"non-categorical" examples include $(\infty, n)$-categories of bordisms as well as the Morita $(\infty,
n)$-category of $E_{n-1}$-algebras in an $(\infty, 1)$-category: people care about bordisms and $E_{n-1}$-algebras
before learning that they have this higher-categorical structure.

I'm interested in hearing about examples like these for $(\infty, \infty)$-categories. It doesn't matter a lot to
me whether something's been rigorously shown to be an example of one of these models or not; and maybe your favorite
example is a different kind of $(\infty, \infty)$-category, such as the ones discussed in [Theo's
question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134057) from several years ago; that's also welcome.

What would be really neat is an example of a new phenomenon at the $n = \infty$ level, so an example of an
$(\infty, \infty)$-category that's not similar to an $(\infty, n)$-category example for any $n$, but that seems
like a lot to ask for.

In addition to Theo's question that I linked above, [this question by Alec
Rhea](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335550) and [this question by Giorgio
Mossa](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73772) are also relevant, asking similar questions for $n$ finite.

Comment: This is obviously not relevant to the main point but I would somewhat dispute the claim that "the $(\infty,\infty)$-category of all $(\infty,\infty)$-categories" is not a bad example. Some would even say that it is an excellent example of a bad example...

Comment: So there are two non-equivalent definition of $(\infty,\infty)$-categories as explained here https://mathoverflow.net/a/134099/22131 I will refer to these as inductive and coinductive $(\infty,\infty)$-categories. If you are using the inductive definition, there is an $(\infty,\infty)$-category of cobordisms and an $(\infty,\infty)$-category of Higher spans. These becam trivial using the coinductive definition however.

Comment: I appreciate the mononymy, but of course there are multiple "Theo"s who do mathematics :) In any case, @SimonHenry got to it before me, but spans are naturally an $(\infty,\infty)$-category. This is true also for spans-with-structure. An important example is the $(\infty,\infty)$-category of (shifted) symplectic manifolds and Lagrangian correspondences, which I believe is carefully defined in upcoming work by Calaque, Haugseng, and Scheimbauer.

Comment: Actually, the category of Lagrangian correspondences can also be extended "down", where you form a sort of "loop spectrum" of $(\infty,\infty)$-categories — what Scheimbauer termed a *tower* in her PhD thesis.

Comment: I am struggling to come up with any examples of $(\infty,\infty)$-categories which are not symmetric monoidal. I guess $\{$codimension-$n$ embedded cobordisms$\}$ is such an example: the $k$-morphisms are $k$-dimensional cobordisms embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$. This should be the free $E_n$-monoidal $(\infty,\infty)$-category generated by an $\infty$-dualizable object.

Comment: (To really give the free something, I would need to be careful about what tangential structure(s) my embedded cobordisms should carry. It's Friday night here, and I don't feel like it.)

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd As somebody scared by shifted symplectic structures, I'm a bit afraid to turn that one at least into an answer like I did with Simon's but I'd love to see that, spans, whatever else you've got as answers.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an $(\infty,\infty)$-category of modules, bimodules, bimodules-between-bimodules, .... over an $E_\infty$ object?

Comment: @TimCampion Not obviously, at least: an (inductive) $(\infty,\infty)$-category is a sequence $(X_n)$ where $X_n$ is an $(\infty,n)$-category with underlying $(\infty,n-1)$-category $X_{n-1}$. But for the Morita $(\infty,n)$-categories of $E_n$-algebras in a symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category $V$ then the objects are different for each $n$. But maybe there should be a Morita $(\infty,\infty)$-category of $V$-$(\infty,\infty)$-categories? (I don't think you can view $E_\infty$-algebras as special $(\infty,\infty)$-categories, as you can for $E_n$, since you are extending "down" not "up".)

Comment: @RuneHaugseng That sounds like a really good point. I don't understand iterated-bimodules very well. To clarify, are you saying that a precise theorem asserting existence of such an $(\infty,\infty)$-category doesn't follow obviously from your work, or rather that there's a serious conceptual obstacle to the idea even making sense? If the latter, then how does this square with Theo's suggestion that iterated spans _do_ form an $(\infty,\infty)$-category? After all, spans are a special case of bimodules in that $Span(C) = Bimod((C,\times)^{op})^{op}$. Do the constructions diverge as we iterate?

Comment: @TimCampion You can extend down: there is a tower whose n'th layer is the $E_n$ Morita category over your fixed $E_\infty$ algebra. Why are you afraid of shifted symplectic geometry?

Comment: @TimCampion Also, thank you for answerifying the comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned by Simon Henry: **The $(\infty,\infty)$-category of cobordisms.**

(Not constructed, but if you did it you could presumably have any of the usual bells and whistles you might want.)

To clarify Simon Henry's comment: The statement is that that $(\infty,\infty)$-category of cobordisms in the coinductive setting is an $\infty$-groupoid by [Cheng's theorem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-007-9081-8) (so it's whatever Thom spectrum you expect by GMTW). In the inductive setting, Cheng's theorem doesn't hold. So non-invertible $(\infty,\infty)$-TFT's should be a thing. I think nobody's formally written down this $(\infty,\infty)$-category -- I assume because $(\infty,n)$-TFTs are hard enough so there's not much demand for it. Please challenge that assumption!

One nice thing about complicial sets (and I guess also comical sets) is that they (ought to) naturally put you in the (more general) inductive setting, and you might hope they'd be a good place to construct these (∞,∞)-categories.

Anyway, this ticks a few boxes:

1. The inductive / coinductive distinction is arguably a "new phenomenon" (though  maybe it's just a "new complication"), and this example already illustrates how it works.
2. It's a super-canonical example, and should be super-interesting for all the reasons its lower brethren are.
3. It's not a category of categories.

Comment: I think Dominic Verity has given a description of this $(\infty,\infty)$-category as a complicial sets. (well, given that the precise connection between complicial sets and $(\infty,\infty)$-categories is still unclear one cannot prove that it really model this object, but it supposed too) I don't know if it is written out in his paper, I only heard gave him talk about this.

Comment: As of a year ago my understanding from talking to Dom was that he had thought seriously about what would go into writing down such a definition, but had not written it up. But it's possible that's partly because he has high standards for what counts as writing and is very modest.

Comment: @TimCampion Thanks, this is a great answer!